# How to scrape href from website, when it doesn't appear in result object?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My goal is to loop through the initial website, to get the URL for each individual camp, and then loop through each of the camps' URLs to scrape the specific data I need.

I would like to loop over the website, find the `href` associated with each camp, and save it into an empty list (so that I can loop through it later). Ideally, camp_html would have the `href` string values from the website that I could append to the base URL. However, when I check the values of camp_html, it doesn't even contain the individual URL that I would append. I know camp_html is a list, but I wanted to manually look through its values so I can figure out which instance I need.

This is the link to the website I am working with: http://find.acacamps.org/search_results.php. I have included my code to show my scraping/looping attempts.

---

```
trial = 'http://find.acacamps.org/search_results.php'
trial_response = requests.get(trial, headers = header)
trial_soup = BeautifulSoup(trial_response.text, 'html.parser')



empty_list = []
camps = trial_soup.find_all('div', {'row'})
for link in camps:
    camp_html = link.find_all('a', href=True)
    for each_camp in camp_html:
        empty_list.append('http://find.acacamps.org' + each_camp['href'])
```

Comment: what is your `search` term?

Comment: Use `Selinium` to fill the form and generate the page further use `bs4` to extract

Comment: url doesn't work for me

Comment: @Ajay I'm not sure what you're asking, but in the main page I am looking for references to each link.

Comment: @SamRaykhman your question is missing necessary information in order to answer it.you missed the part of `What type of camp do you want?` as you are refereeing the link directly without the post parameters. please [edit] your question and include full details.

Answer (score 0):

it need Post requests and your selector is too broad and make false results.
here minimal working post data, if you need more specific results watch post request in `Network` tab of browser console (F12)

```
postData = {
  'search': 'search',
  'facets[camp_type]':'day_camp',
  'open[choices-made-content]': 'true'
}

trial_response = requests.post(trial, headers=headers, data=postData)
trial_soup = BeautifulSoup(trial_response.text, 'html.parser')

empty_list = []

camp_html = trial_soup.select('div.row .col-sm-4 a')
for each_camp in camp_html:
    empty_list.append('http://find.acacamps.org' + each_camp['href'])

print(empty_list)
```